# Angular watch doesn't triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

$watch doesn't triggered then I change my datepicker. Why?

Update: I've noticed that my departDate and returnDate doesn't change when I select a new date. What could be a reason?

```
 var app = angular.module("fly");

(function(){

    function Controller($scope, searchData) {



        $scope.$watch('departDate', function(newValue, oldValue){

            $scope.departDate = newValue;
            searchData.setDateFrom(newValue);

            if(searchData.getDateFrom() > searchData.getDateTo()) {
                searchData.setDateFrom(newValue);
                searchData.setDateTo(newValue);
                $scope.returnDate = newValue;

            }

        });

        $scope.$watch('returnDate', function(newValue, oldValue){

            $scope.returnDate = newValue;
            searchData.setDateTo(newValue);

            if(searchData.getDateFrom() > searchData.getDateTo()) {
                searchData.setDateFrom(newValue);
                searchData.setDateTo(newValue);
                $scope.departDate = newValue;
            }

        });


        $scope.datePickerStates = {
            open1:false,
            open2:false
        };

        $scope.open = function($event, opened) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.datePickerStates[opened] = true;
        };


        $scope.today = function() {
            $scope.dt = new Date();
        };
        $scope.today();

        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.dt = null;
        };

        $scope.toggleMin = function() {
            $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
        };
        $scope.toggleMin();

        $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yyyy',
            startingDay: 1
        };

        $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
        $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    }

    app.controller('DatePickerController', Controller);


})();
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"  min-date="minDate" ng-model="departDate" is-open="datePickerStates.open1" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open($event, 'open1')" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"   min-date="minDate" ng-model="returnDate" is-open="datePickerStates.open2" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open($event, 'open2')" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

UPDATE:

This where I declare my nested controllers and using directives.

```
<div ng-controller="DatePickerController">
    <div ng-controller="PassengerController as pd">
        <div ng-controller="PlaceController as pc">
            <search-bar-md></search-bar-md>
            <search-bar-sm></search-bar-sm>
            <search-bar-xs></search-bar-xs>

            <pre>{{departDate}}</pre>
            <pre>{{returnDate}}</pre>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("fly", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);


app.factory('searchData', function () {

    var data = {
        travelFrom: '',
        travelTo: '',
        dateToday: new Date(),
        dateFrom: new Date(),
        dateTo: new Date()
    };

    return {
        getTravelFrom : function() {
            return data.travelFrom;
        },
        setTravelFrom : function(travelFrom){
            data.travelFrom = travelFrom;
        },
        getTravelTo : function(){
            return data.travelTo;
        },
        setTravelTo : function(travelTo){
            data.travelTo = travelTo;
        },
        /*** Travel dates ***/
        getTodayDate : function(){
            return data.dateToDay;
        },
        getDateFrom : function(){
            return data.dateFrom;
        },
        setDateFrom : function(dateFrom){
            data.dateFrom = dateFrom;
        },
        getDateTo : function(){
            return data.dateTo;
        },
        setDateTo : function(dateTo){
            data.dateTo = dateTo;
        }

    };
});




app.directive('navBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/navbar/navbar.html'
    };
});


app.directive('searchBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search-bar/search-bar.html'
    };
});

app.directive('searchBarMd', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search-bar/search-bar-md.html'
    };
});

app.directive('searchBarSm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search-bar/search-bar-sm.html'
    };
});

app.directive('searchBarXs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search-bar/search-bar-xs.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't see any datepicker that is using either of these variables you are watching listed here.

Comment: @Claies, sorry! Edited!

Comment: May be you should show your `searchData` service, so we can see the problem.  http://plnkr.co/edit/y1LCEF71AgB2qbiPhjIQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a wrapper object should solve it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/o8iwrVIYJq9wG74f0uR0?p=preview

Main change is adding the wrapper object in `DatePickerController`:

```
$scope.dates = {}
```

Then use that object to store the dates as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="DatePickerController">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"  min-date="minDate" ng-model="dates.departDate" is-open="datePickerStates.open1" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open($event, 'open1')" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"   min-date="minDate" ng-model="dates.returnDate" is-open="datePickerStates.open2" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open($event, 'open2')" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason why this works is because ng-model replaces the instances of the referenced objects with others. Each controller has it's own scope but it inherits from it parent scope, but when using nested controllers with ng-model, only the inmediate $scope's object is modified. For example if we have controller1 and a nested controller2:

```
//Initial state:
controller1Scope.property='initial'
controller2Scope.property='initial' //Inherited from controller1 scope

//After ng-model="property" input is changed to 'new_value':
controller1Scope.property='initial'
controller2Scope.property='new_value'
```

If you use a wrapper object then it's shared in all the scopes, and when some of it's properties is changed, it affects all of them:

```
//Initial state:
controller1Scope.wrapper={property:'initial'}
controller2Scope.wrapper={property:'initial'} //Inherited from controller1 scope

//After ng-model="wrapper.property" input is changed to 'new_value':
controller1Scope.wrapper={property:'new_value'}
controller2Scope.wrapper={property:'new_value'} //Inherited from controller1 scope
```

Comment: I've nested controllers, probably that's a reason. If I move controller on the same level with datepickers all works good as you said, why it doesn't work when I use few nested controllers? Updating my question in a sec..

Comment: Have you tried controllerAs syntax? Maybe for some reason the datepicker is using an scope different that the one of your controller, probably the top most scope under the $rootScope.

Comment: Now I see the updated question... could you try controllerAs also for the DatePickerController?

Comment: But it works if I switch DatePickerController with PlaceController, of course PlaceController stop working..

Comment: Try using a wrapper object  for both dates like in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/o8iwrVIYJq9wG74f0uR0?p=preview

Comment: Whoops. Actually that worked! Thanks! Could you please explain in details, why did it helped?

Comment: Ng-model replaces objects in the $scope directly. So it was changing the PlaceController's scope but not the others. When you create a wrapper object, it's shared in all the scopes and it's properties are changed by ng-model allowing $watches to be placed in all of the scopes.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind to update your main post so that I can mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$scope.departDate` and  `$scope.returnDate` in controller with some default value. 
JS:

```
function Controller($scope, searchData) {
    $scope.departDate = ''; //you can set your own default value
    $scope.returnDate = ''; //you can set your own default value
... }
```